# Stop rollback of anonymous DO code block?

Tags: postgresql, rollback, postgresql-12

I'm executing some code through this anonymous [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-do.html) code feature. I am observing that whenever it fails, all changes made are discarded and the database is rolled back to a state as it was before it began. How can I stop this functionality?

Comment: you can't. `do` is a single statement.

Comment: are there any workarounds?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am getting a "statement aborted" message when this block fails. Would you know if there is a timer related to it for long-running statements?

Answer (score 2):

You can commit inside the DO, as long as it is not already inside a transaction.

```
create table foo (z double precision);

do language PLPGSQL $$
declare i int; 
begin 
  for i in 1 .. 12 loop 
    insert into foo values (sqrt(10-i)); 
    commit; 
  end loop; 
end;$$;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot take square root of a negative number
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into foo values (sqrt(10-i))"
> PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at SQL statement
> ```

```
select count(*) from foo;
```

> 10

Comment: This results in: 
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at COMMIT

Comment: @Victor I only get that error I try to do it from inside another transaction block.  If you are not in a transaction already, then it works fine for me, in all still-supported versions.

Comment: you are right. I ran this in PgAdmin. Looks like it wraps everything into a transaction. In console this worked. Thank you